# What's a word for saying 'entering a room suddenly and fast'?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary, verbs

I'm looking for a word that means 'enter a room fast and suddenly'. Using a dictionary I got the word 'to plunge' - however I'm not sure if that's correct.

When looking up 'to plunge' (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plunge) it seems not to be completely correct, especially when looking at the example sentences.

So, is 'to plunge' also used with the meaning of 'entering a room fast and suddenly'? If not, what is such a word?

Comment: I think the proper term is 'to kramer', as in "With his wild hair askew, he kramered into the room."

Comment: @oosterwal: Of course! http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXSGV5wEv1o

Comment: @oosterwal: You should make it an [answer](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Kramering).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[**Burst**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/burst)

Definition #2 from Collins English Dictionary:

> (intr) to come, go, etc., suddenly and forcibly. *He burst into the room*.

Comment: For OP's exact context, *burst in* is definitely first choice. *Barging* is more likely to reference things (and people) disrupted by the sudden entry. *Plunging* is more often metaphorical (*he plunged into his work*) unless the space being entered is full of liquid (i.e. - a swimming pool)

Answer (score 9):

**[Barge](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/barge)**

Definition #2 (verb) from Merriam-Webster Dicitonary:

> (intr) to thrust oneself heedlessly or unceremoniously. *She barged through the door without even knocking*

Comment: I think "Barge" also has a feeling of violence/aggression associated with it.

Answer (score 8):

Consider also [**storm**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/storm), from the Free Dictionary:

> To move or rush tumultuously, violently, or angrily: *stormed into the room.*

Comment: This one actually is a literal translation of the word in my language - I didn't know this can be said in English as well.

Answer (score 4):

While I was making it up as a joke, @Callithumpian has encouraged me to offer **"Kramering"** as a real answer.  Here is a [definition from the Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Kramering), and [here is a visual explanation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXSGV5wEv1o) of the origin of the term.

Answer (score 3):

[Rush](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rush) from the Free Dictionary:

> 1. To make a sudden or swift attack or charge.

Example: “He rushed into the room to break the bad news.”

Answer (score 2):

She exploded into the room and hurled the knife at him.

Answer (score 1):

Suddenly and fast, as in an invasion:

They crashed into the room and made the arrest.

Answer (score 1):

[irrupt](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&noj=1&q=irrupt&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=MWHLTdT_IdS_tgejpIGKCA&ved=0CBYQkQ4)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps **charged** as in following?

> She *charged* into the room to see what was amiss.

Answer (score -1):

I'd most often use " burst into the room" or maybe "barged into..." although to me the second also has the suggestion of interrupting someone

Comment: This is just an echo of the highest-voted answers. When answering, please add unique suggestions or information.