# Is there a word or an idiom for barging in a room with anger?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, expressions, idioms

Opening a door frustrated and rushing in like you are about to scold someone inside... Barging in a room with anger. Is there a word or idiom for that, other than storm in?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19138/whats-a-word-for-saying-entering-a-room-suddenly-and-fast

Comment: I think that "raging into" would work in place of "barging into." I've always loved the comparison of a person's intrusion into a peaceful setting to the behavior of a barge, though: The momentum of a fully laden barge seems almost irresistible—and certainly impossible to ignore.

Answer (score 10):

Storming in and barging in are great, but for some added oomph, how about **erupting** into the room?

Comment: +1, 'Barging' implies rudeness a bit more than anger, but still works well. 'Storming' seems best, as that implies both rushing and anger. I get more enthusiasm than anger from 'erupting', but anger is usually pretty enthusiastic.

Comment: To me "erupting into the room" comes across a little strange, as "erupting" has an association of "bursting *out*". But that may just be me :)

Answer (score 10):

"Burst into the room" sounds good.

Comment: This was my first thought, too. It doesn't necessarily imply frustration or anger though, just entering a room energetically (e.g. you could burst into a room joyfully). Context is necessary for the emotion(s) associated with the action.

Answer (score 5):

1) Barged in
2) Stormed in
3) Broke in
4) he/she pushed forward into the room with anger.
5) thrust ahead.

Comment: *Barge* and *storm* are perfect fits in my mind. The others are stretches. *Break in* doesn't suggest any particular attitude or even energy, as you can silently and carefully *break into* a room with no anger or frustration on your mind at all.

Comment: after a thought, I agree.

Answer (score 4):

**Charged** into the room

> **[charge](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/charge)**
>
> *intransitive verb*
>
> :  to rush forward in or as if in assault :  attack; also :  to charge
>   an opponent in sports
>   <sub>[Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/charge)</sub>

A couple of examples

> UNCONTROLLABLE anger surged through Wilson as he **charged** into the
>   room.
>  <sub>[Google Books: Crimson Moon by Rebecca York](https://books.google.com/books?id=NtBHMuyY5D8C&pg=PT27#v=onepage&q&f=false)</sub>

and

> 'Wayward and contrary!' Gwenhwyvar cried. 'Easily given to despair!'
>   She **charged into the room** and planted herself before us, fists on
>   hips. 'Gwenhwyvar,' Arthur said, somewhat startled. 'I thought you
>   were asleep.' 'Listen to the both of you,' she **scolded**. 'I will tell
>   you what troubles me, shall I? You haughty Britons think you are the
>   only men alive who know how to throw a spear.'
>   <sub>[Google Books: Pendragon By Sahın Akbulut](https://books.google.com/books?id=KcUGCQAAQBAJ&pg=PT168#v=onepage&q&f=false)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

**Loaded for bear**

To be prepared, mentally and/or physically, for extreme opposition; typically used in reference to an aggressive or potentially violent situation.

For example:

*He showed up loaded for bear and wouldn't leave until he gave everyone a piece of his mind.*

Comment: Worth noting that this idiom is based on arming oneself. It is sometimes used in military contexts. A helicopter that hasn't fired any of its missiles is l[oaded for bear](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/loaded_for_bear).

Answer (score 2):

You can consider ***flounce into***.

> Go or move in an exaggeratedly impatient or angry manner
>
> [*OD / flounce*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/flounce)

But the strongest sense of anger can be conveyed with ***explode into***.

> Again the door burst open and again it slammed against the wall. A genuinely angry President **exploded into the room**...
>
> <sub>*Madame President* by Wee Dilts</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You could say the person went ***ballistic***.

> to be extremely and uncontrollable *[sic]* furious
>   *Fred went* ballistic, *and managed to punch 5 holes in the wall, in addition to throwing a microwave halfway across his house.*
>   <sub>[Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Ballistic)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

He came barreling into the room. Describes intensity and single-mindedness but not necessarily anger.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the idiom **muscle in**.

> Forcibly intrude on or interfere with something, as in The children
>   were determined not to allow the school bully to muscle in. [Colloquial; 1920s]  [(Free Dictionary)](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/muscle+in)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the informal idiom: "Bust the door down" or "Bust the door open." In this context, "bust" is used informally for the word "break". Depending on the context, this idiom can suggest a violent disposition towards whomever is "behind the door", either actually or metaphorically. "I will bust the door down to get answers."